# Why should one use update-locale instead of directly setting LANGUAGE?

Tags: debian, environment-variables, locale, etc

In Debian, I am used to set the `LANGUAGE` environment variable in `/etc/environment`.  Now with Debian testing I found `/etc/default/locale`, which is updated by `update-locale`.  The `update-locale` man page states it performs some sanity checks but never details them, so: what are these checks?  are they important or even essential?  can I set `/etc/default/locale` as I did `/etc/environment`, or should I absolutely use `update-locale`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are just two [sanity checks](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/blob/sid/debian/local/usr_sbin/update-locale):

- the requested locale must exist (otherwise `update-locale` exits and `/etc/default/locale` isn't modified)
- if a value is specified for `LANGUAGE`, it must be valid (otherwise it is ignored)

So there's nothing which *requires* you to use `update-locale` instead of editing `/etc/default/locale` yourself, but it is a good idea to use it to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for.  Since I always did `/etc/environment`, I guess I am qualified enough to do `/etc/default/locale` myself, if only because I am too lazy to use `update-locale`.  Not that it takes much more effort.