# Debian 9: How to set English language with German Locale?

Tags: linux, debian, locale, language

I want to use **English language** with **German locale** settings.

---

Right now my system runs with the following setup (configured during installation procedure in Debian Expert Installer):

- Language: `English - English (Default)`
- Country, territory or area: `other -> Europe -> Austria`
- Country to base default locale settings on: `United States - en_US.UTF-8`
- Keyboard: `German`

---

**My question now is:**

How can I preserve English language but switch the current locale (`United States - en_US.UTF-8`) to desired German locale (`de_DE.UTF-8`)?

During installation procedure this was not possible because an error occurred ("Invalid language/locale settings combination detected").

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15291/set-lc-but-not-lc-all

Comment: I was just looking on how to setup English with Dutch locale (same problem) and the first Google hit is this one. Long live StackExchange :-)

Comment: Found this in "hot network questions" and now I'm interested: What are you trying to achieve? English, but with some words different specifically for German speakers? Like "I just took an Abitur exam" or "This is a train from Deutsche Bahn"?

Comment: @Fabian I suspect the use-case here is to have English messages, but German date formats etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`en_DE` doesn’t exist as a default locale, so you can’t select English localised for German-speaking countries as a locale during installation. ([Why should one use update-locale instead of directly setting LANGUAGE?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348502/86440) describes the checks involved in choosing a locale.)

There are two approaches to achieve what you’re after.

1. One is to create a new locale with your settings; see [How to (easily) be able to use a new en_** locale?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209853/86440) for details.
2. The other is to set up your locale settings in a finer-grained fashion, using [the various `LC_` variables](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html); for example:

   ```
   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
   export LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
   export LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
   ```

   or, if you want German to be the default except for messages:

   ```
   export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
   export LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
   ```

   (and unset any other conflicting `LC_` variables, in particular `LC_ALL` which overrides all other settings). You can check your settings using the `locale` program; see [How does the "locale" program work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449318/86440) for details.

Comment: Since LANG is only a fallback, your proposal does not work in case there are other LC_* variables.

Comment: Well that’s the whole point of using `LANG` here, but I’ve clarified that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help Stephen! Do I first have to generate the German locale before I can type it into `/etc/default/locale`? I guess right now I only have US-locale existent, so I fear `de_DE.UTF-8` is not yet available on my system?

Comment: @Dave you’ll need to make it available, yes, either by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` or by installing `locales-all`. You shouldn’t edit `/etc/default/locale` directly, but use `update-locale` instead (see the first link in the answer).

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks! Could you give me a pointer on where to add the export commands to (on archlinux) to make them available for all programs and be set on boot?

Comment: @bonanza I don’t know what the idiomatic approach is on Arch Linux. You could ask a new question if you like!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer by Stephen and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/162714) I built the desired `en_DE` locale together with some merged installing instructions for download [here](https://github.com/leander-j/en_DE). Feel free to try it out and give some feedback.