# How to install Debian 10 (Buster) in English language but with German locales?

Tags: debian, locale, debian-installer, language, debian-cd

Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456726/debian-9-how-to-set-english-language-with-german-locale) considering Debian 9 (Stretch), maybe there are some updates available.

---

I want to use **English language** with **German locales**.

Is there an option available to select this configuration **already during Debian installation** (maybe within *Advanced options* -> *Expert install*)?

Up to now I would use the following approach:

1. Choose language: `English - English`
2. Country, territory or area: `other` -> `Europe` -> `Germany`
3. Country to base default locale settings on: `de_DE.UTF-8`

---

Unfortunately, pairing `English language` with `German locales` is [not provided by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456730/241507) as you can also see in the next screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

---

However, Ubuntu and its derivates provide such an option already during installation in the next step after selecting the desired `language`:

[image: Screenshot of the desired s tate]

Afterwards, checking `locale` leads to:

```
user@pc:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

=> This is exactly what I want in Debian.

---

**Question:**

Is there any possibility to choose the desired configuration already during installation? Or is it only possible to adjust this after completing the whole installation progress?

Comment: Very complicated to modify that installation process. Recommend ajusting it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose the expert installer you can add one or more additional locales and then choose the default locale, but you need to change your `LC_XXX` variables manually as described by [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456730/332764).

Regarding the locale settings this is the same as using the default installation method and running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` afterwards.

The selections would look like this:

1. In grub choose `Advanced options ->` and `Graphical expert install` or `Expert install`:
2. Select a language: `English - English`
3. Select your location: `other -> Europe -> Germany`
4. Configuring locales: `United States - en_US.UTF-8`
5. Configuring (additional) locales: `de_DE.UTF-8`
6. Select the default locale for the installed system: `en_US.UTF-8`

And modify the individual locale settings as needed when the installation completes.

To update the global locale settings you could use:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 $(printf 'LC_%s=de_DE.UTF-8 '\
 NUMERIC TIME MONETARY PAPER NAME ADDRESS TELEPHONE MEASUREMENT IDENTIFICATION)
```

Or add the variables to your local shell initialization file. To add the German settings to your `~/.bashrc` if the default locale is `en_US.UTF-8`, you could use:

```
printf 'export LC_%s=de_DE.UTF-8\n'\
 NUMERIC TIME MONETARY PAPER NAME ADDRESS TELEPHONE MEASUREMENT IDENTIFICATION >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: One option would be usage of `en_IE.UTF-8` as its closely to German locales and uses English language as well.